How to stop sign up user in supabase except from your app
I have a pretty basic problem, however I can't seem to find a solution after searching on google. I am using the supabase email auth feature, however, if anyone gets the anon key and url they could just invoke the sign up function and create a user, which they could then sign in into my app.
I was wondering, should then the anon key just be private, if so how can I hide it in both IOS(swift) and Android (Kotlin/Java) like .env files when doing web dev? But I read too that the anon key is a public key.
I also thought of disallowing sign ups except through and edge function that accepts a secret key and then does the sign up.
However, all of this seems pretty complicated for what seems an easy matter. Are there any more better ideas? Thanks!

It's impossible to have a "secret key" in an app, because an attacker can always retrieve it in the same way they can retrieve the anon key. You can use an edge function with app check to verify that the request is coming from your app, but what does the person gain by creating an account outside of your app's process and what is the issue if they then use this account to sign in to the app?
